# More condensed version of \parshape

Tags: indentation, paragraphs, width

`\parshape` can handle arbitrary paragraph shapes. One extreme is contained within [How to layout irregular paragraph shape](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32226/5764), where it can handle setting paragraphs like this:

[image]

However, a simplified (and far more often-used) version of `\parshape` typically switches between *two* lengths over a number of lines. For example,

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}

\parshape 5
  0pt 0.5\textwidth
  0pt 0.5\textwidth
  0pt 0.5\textwidth
  0pt 0.5\textwidth
  0.5\textwidth 0.5\textwidth
\noindent\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

However, the use of explicit line lengths that are duplicated makes for cumbersome input - the more lines, the more duplication. Would it be possible to create a macro `\newparshape` (say) that would provide the same as the above, yet allow for input of the form

```
\newparshape{<num>}{<ind> <wd>}[<indL> <wdL>]
```

where it would set `<num>` lines with indent `<ind>` and width `<wd>`, while subsequent line (`<num>`+1 onward) set with indent `<indL>` and width `<wdL>`. The above example (default) usage would then be replaced with

```
\newparshape{4}{0pt 0.5\textwidth}[0.5\textwidth 0.5\textwidth]
\noindent\lipsum[1]
```

---

In a more general setting, expanding the restriction of setting only *two* lengths to more would be to generate `\newparshape` to accept input of the form

```
\newparshape
  {3}{0pt 0.5\textwidth}% 3 lines with 0pt indent and width 0.5\textwidth, followed by
  {2}{0.25\textwidth 200pt}% 2 lines with 0.25\textwidth indent and width 200pt, followed by
  {..}{...}% .. lines with ... and ..., followed by
  [...]% subsequent lines with indent ... and width ...
```

Of course, a different interface altogether is also acceptable. For example, something more `tabular`-like:

```
\newparshape{{4}{0pt 0.5\textwidth}{2}{0.25\textwidth 200pt}{..}{...}}[...]
```

where pairs of arguments are grouped within the first argument of `\newparshape{<lines>}[<other>]`, followed by a possible specification of `<other>` for the treatment of subsequent lines in an optional argument.

Comment: You may want to look at `\hangindent` and `\hangafter` (I think that's how the primitives are called), which are a simplified form of `\parshape`.

Comment: If you are feeling adventurous, I could write up an `xgalley`-based answer :-)

Comment: @JosephWright I'm feeling curious – is `xgalley` supposed to be able to do this? Because I was about to ask another Q specific to expl3's coffins.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum

\parindent0pt
\parskip\bigskipamount

\makeatletter
\def\newparshape{\parshape\@npshape0{}}
\def\@npshape#1#2#3{\ifx\\#3\expandafter\@@@npshape\else\expandafter\@@npshape\fi
{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\def\@@npshape#1#2#3#4#5{%
\ifnum#3>\z@\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
{\expandafter\@@npshape\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1+1\relax}{#2 #4 #5}{\numexpr#3-1\relax}{#4}{#5}}%
{\@npshape{#1}{#2}}}
\def\@@@npshape#1#2#3{#1 #2 }
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\newparshape{3}{5pt}{5cm}{4}{10pt}{2cm}{1}{5cm}{8cm}\\\lipsum[1]

\newparshape{2}{5cm}{5cm}{2}{4cm}{5cm}{2}{3cm}{5cm}{1}{0pt}{\textwidth}\\\lipsum[1]



\end{document}
```