# Textbox of arbitrary shape

Tags: boxes, shapes

Textboxes are rectangles which can contains text and other stuffs.
I was wondering if there is some package that allows to create textboxes with arbitrary shapes.

I mean, can I obtain something like this?

[image]

Hope tags are correct.

Comment: Look at this posting http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127504/more-condensed-version-of-parshape

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first package I can think of is, obviously, *shapepar*.  You might also want to have a look to the *wrapfig* package.

**Addition**

However, what you request could also be obtained, without loading any package, by means of TeX primitive commands: try saying

```
\hangindent = -.5\linewidth % for instance
\hangafter  = 7 % say
```

at the beginning of a paragraph, and see what happens.  Then try playing around with the values `.5` and `7` (the latter must be an integer).