# nested adjust width block - remove whitespace

Tags: spacing, pdf, ebook

I am currently making a document with [this environment](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/ebook).

I would like to have a tabbed over section of text, which I am doing with `\adjustwidth`. I would like to have another tabbed over section within this section without whitespace above and below. How can I do this?

### I realize that I did not use the ebook layout for the MWE. I didn't want to put all of the extra stuff included in ebook. I apologize.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{changepage} % for use of a tabbed over section for a small portion of the text e.g. in chapter 1

\begin{document}


\begin{adjustwidth}{2.5em}{0pt}
I want these words at this level \\ 
More at this level \\ 
\begin{adjustwidth}{2.5em}{0pt}
    I want these words at this level \\ 
    I do not want the whitespace above and below this level \\ 
\end{adjustwidth}
How can I get rid of the whitespace above and below the nested adjustwidth, or what's the best way to do this?\\ 
\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is fairly straight forward with `\parshape` rather than `adjustwidth`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still a little new to all of this. I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the `par`agraph `shape` based on the specific number of lines:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{changepage}

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133660/5764
\makeatletter
\def\newparshape{\parshape\@npshape0{}}
\def\@npshape#1#2#3{\ifx\\#3\expandafter\@@@npshape\else\expandafter\@@npshape\fi
{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\def\@@npshape#1#2#3#4#5{%
\ifnum#3>\z@\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
{\expandafter\@@npshape\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1+1\relax}{#2 #4 #5}{\numexpr#3-1\relax}{#4}{#5}}%
{\@npshape{#1}{#2}}}
\def\@@@npshape#1#2#3{#1 #2 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustwidth}{2.5em}{0pt}
I want these words at this level \\ 
More at this level \\ 
\begin{adjustwidth}{2.5em}{0pt}
  I want these words at this level \\ 
  I do not want the whitespace above and below this level \\ 
\end{adjustwidth}
How can I get rid of the whitespace above and below the nested adjustwidth, or what's the best way to do this?\\ 
\end{adjustwidth}

\newparshape{2}{2.5em}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2em}{2}{5em}{\dimexpr\linewidth-5em}{1}{2.5em}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2.5em}\\
\noindent I want these words at this level \\ 
More at this level \\ 
  I want these words at this level \\ 
  I do not want the whitespace above and below this level \\ 
How can I get rid of the whitespace above and below the nested adjustwidth, or what's the best way to do this?\\ 

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\newparshape` is from [More condensed version of `\parshape`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127504/5764).