# Error when executing a \parshape code in texlive 2016

Tags: macros, errors

Trying to execute @DavidCarlisle [code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133660/54817) I still having errors

> ! Missing number, treated as zero.  
>                      \  l.21 ...{5cm}{4}{10pt}{2cm}{1}{5cm}{8cm}\ \lipsum[
>                                                     1] A number should have been here; I inserted '0'. (If you can't figure out why I needed
>   to see a number, look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
>
> ! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.  
>                      \  l.21 ...{5cm}{4}{10pt}{2cm}{1}{5cm}{8cm}\ \lipsum[
>                                                     1] I was expecting to see '<', '=', or '>'. Didn't.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum

\parindent0pt
\parskip\bigskipamount

\makeatletter
\def\newparshape{\parshape\@npshape0{}}
\def\@npshape#1#2#3{\ifx\\#3\expandafter\@@@npshape\else\expandafter\@@npshape\fi
{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\def\@@npshape#1#2#3#4#5{%
\ifnum#3>\z@\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
{\expandafter\@@npshape\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1+1\relax}{#2 #4 #5}{\numexpr#3-1\relax}{#4}{#5}}%
{\@npshape{#1}{#2}}}
\def\@@@npshape#1#2#3{#1 #2 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newparshape{3}{5pt}{5cm}{4}{10pt}{2cm}{1}{5cm}{8cm}\\\lipsum[1]

\newparshape{2}{5cm}{5cm}{2}{4cm}{5cm}{2}{3cm}{5cm}{1}{0pt}{\textwidth}\\\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Note that I have `texlive 2016`, any suggestions.

Comment: There has crept some typing error in that answer. `\    \lipsum[1]` had to be `\\\lipsum[1]`. Meaning the `\newparshape` ends with `\\\` and then the text follows. I have made that correction in the original code by @DavidCarlisle and in your code above.

Comment: @PietvanOostrum I happened to see some code of mine that strangely ending up here with “backslash space” instead of “double backslash” (and caused errors to the user trying to use it, of course). I don't know how and when the mistake crept in, though. `:(`. A tip: for getting a double backslash in comments, use “double backquote, double backslash, double backquote”: ``\\``

Comment: @PietvanOostrum That is definitely an answer to this question.

Comment: @egreg Is this the site bug?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is due to copying code corrupted by the infamous \\ site bug

Comment: @cfr I think so; since the original code has since been fixed, this question is now useless.