# Let text body float around marginpar

Tags: marginpar, page, layout, parshape

How do I create a marginpar so that it is indented into the text body and the text body floats around the marginpar?

I know how to create a marginpar:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\marginpar{Here are some more information about this section.}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

This creates A, but I want B.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps the `cutwin` package can be of help to you.

Comment: Thank you @PeterWilson for the hint. At first this looked promising. But some of the paragraphs, where I want to apply this, break to the next page. which does not work well with cutwin.

Comment: Is it maybe possible to have something like a hanging indent from the end of the lines?

Comment: `\parshape` must be the thing I need: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127504/more-condensed-version-of-parshape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrapfig environment takes an optional argument saying how much to overhang into the margin. Usage is in the example. With reasonably new LaTeX you can use `\dimexpr` for calculating the sum, or you can use the `calc` package and omit `\dimexpr`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{shortvrb}
\MakeShortVerb"
\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}[\dimexpr \marginparwidth+\marginparsep]{5cm}
  Here is some information about this section. And are some more
  facts about this section.
\end{wrapfigure}

At the beginning of the document or after "\newpage" the top lines
of text will align naturally.
\lipsum[1]\marginpar{Here is how a marginpar is placed entirely in the marginpar region.}

\lipsum[1]

\section*{Section}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}[\dimexpr \marginparwidth+\marginparsep]{5cm}
 \vspace{-\intextsep}
 In general locations, the wrapfigure is separated by "\intextsep",
 so if you don't want the extra space, get rid of it with a negative
 "\vspace" or by setting "\intextsep" to zero.
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```