# Recognize shape in image and get positional info of it

Tags: tikz-pgf, wrap, text-manipulation, workflow, shapepar

I am aware of the existence of the package `wrapfig` and features to [shape text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67032/fitting-text-to-a-shape-in-tikz) more sophisticatedly ([also this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32226/how-to-layout-irregular-paragraph-shape)). My question aims for some advanced tool to be used with them:

> Is there a workflow to have shapes in images recognized ?

*(1)* compare comments and edit

> Afterwards, how do I make this information accessible in LaTeX ?

Ultimately I would like to have pictures with white or transparent areas as background. The lesser requirements to the 'background'-part in the image do it, the better.

These **edges** should be **detected** and be made available in some way (eg. TikZ-nodes).

An obvious usage would be to have text flow around the content of an image nicely - imagine eg. a product shot of a [lamp](https://thumb1.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/3572276/318130796/stock-photo-table-lamp-isolated-on-white-background-318130796.jpg) on the right of ones text. *(1)*

---

### edit:

*(1)* After looking at `pullquotes` (mentioned in the comments by Torbjørn T.) I must say it seems to be covering all needs with picture inserts.
Apparently it is using [ImageMagick's edge-detection](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/view/head:/pullquote.dtx#L2103):

```
  [...]
  \edef\@tmp
  {%
    convert \img@pq\space -resize \strip@pt\@tempdima x\strip@pt\@tempdimb! -bordercolor white -border 10x10 -morphology Erode Disk:10.3 -resize
    \number\objrows@pq x\number\objlines@pq! -black-threshold
    95\@percentchar\space-monochrome \img@pq.pqshape.txt
  }%
  \immediate\write18{\@tmp}%
  [...]
```

However, it is still unclear to me how this data is passed on to LaTeX and if this can be used in other ways (eg. TikZ-nodes).

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53073/two-column-text-with-circular-insert/70169#70169 https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45958/implementing-a-pullquotes-algorithm-in-latex

Comment: @TorbjørnT. thanks for this lightning quick comment.`pullquotes` looks very interesting! It probably covers any text-flow wish. I have not yet read all of the content, but off the top of my head this questions strikes: Does this integrate with eg. TikZ such that I could work further with the shape inside LaTeX ?

Comment: I don't think so. The (experimental) feature that recognizes the shape uses ImageMagick, so it must be an image format that ImageMagick knows about.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. don't get me wrong, I was referring to the means provided by the package. So lets say I have a .png and it detected some edges; how does it tell LaTeX about it? Could one retrieve nodes for a TikZ Image from this detection?

Comment: I really don't know much more than that those two posts I linked to exist, and you can read those just as well as I can.

Comment: Alright, I just thought you might have some more insight. The reason why I was asking is, that I could only find [this line](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/view/head:/pullquote.dtx#L2103) `convert \img@pq\space [...] -bordercolor white -border 10x10 [...]` but am unable to determine how it's then passed to (La)TeX; obviously it's not using TikZ-nodes at that point. Thank you for pointing out these related posts though!

Comment: The information from `convert` is stored in, I think, `pq-duck.pdf.pqshape.txt `, for example. This specifies, I think, what is essentially a kind of mask for the image. (Not exactly a mask, but more like a mask without holes.) But what do you want to turn it into Ti*k*Z nodes for?

Comment: @cfr, well as the text-flow problem is solved, I would say: -having text flow along edges; -basis for annotating dynamically (so not in some external program); -just generally being well accessible. The question is purposely broad, because I might use it as a basis for some follow-ups. Hence, the information and a general idea like how to translate the information from the file you mentioned to Ti*k*Z nodes is absolutely satisfactory for me as an answer.