# Escape nested list indentation

Tags: enumerate, indentation, enumitem

My goal is to have a list with Arabic numbering, with each Arabic number having a sub-list with Latin numbering. Each Arabic-numbered item represents a general category, with each Latin-numbered item representing a question within that category.

After each question, I want to be able to type up the answer. Thus, I attempted this with an enumerate, another enumerate within that, and then whenever I needed to write a paragraph to answer the question, I would end the inner enumerate, write the paragraph, then resume the enumerate once I've completed it. Example below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item{}

        \begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*)]
            \item{Question:}
        \end{enumerate}

        My answer

        \begin{enumerate}[resume,label=\roman*)]
            \item{Question 2:}
        \end{enumerate}

        My second answer
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The issue with this approach is that the answer text is bound to the outer enumerate's indentation. If I was to exit the outer enumerate as well, I would not be able to re-start the enumerate without re-starting the numbering as well, as I cannot seem to use enumerate without a present item.

As an additional note, I am looking to keep the Latin-numbered list items within the indentation whilst allowing the paragraph text to remain un-indented.

What is the best way for me to obtain the desired effect?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**REVISED ANSWER** (using `\leftskip`)

This revised answer will allow pagebreaks in the middle of the answer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,lipsum}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\newcommand\myanswer[1]{{%
  \leftskip-\dimexpr\leftmargini+\leftmarginii\relax #1\par}}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item{}

    \begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*),parsep=5pt]
        \item Question: What is the margination if my question
          goes on long enough?

    \myanswer{My answer shows that the answer will retain the
      proper margination if one uses the macro
      \textbackslash myanswer.}
    \end{enumerate}


    \begin{enumerate}[resume,label=\roman*),parsep=5pt]
        \item{Question 2:}

    \myanswer{My second answer}
    \end{enumerate}

    \begin{enumerate}[resume, label=\roman*),parsep=5pt]
        \item{Question 3:}

    \myanswer{My third answer \lipsum[4-8]}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Maybe something like this, using `listparindent` to undo indentation for extra paragraphs of an item.  The key here for usage is to

1. Make the answer part of the same `\item` that comprises the question.
2. use `\myanswer` to typeset your answer, if it is longer than a single line.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\newcommand\myanswer[1]{\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item{}

    \begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*),parsep=5pt,
      listparindent=-\dimexpr\leftmargini+\leftmarginii\relax]
        \item Question: What is the margination if my question
          goes on long enough?

    \myanswer{My answer shows that the answer will retain the
      proper margination if one uses the macro
      \textbackslash myanswer.}
    \end{enumerate}


    \begin{enumerate}[resume,label=\roman*),parsep=5pt,
      listparindent=-\dimexpr\leftmargini+\leftmarginii\relax]
        \item{Question 2:}

    \myanswer{My second answer}
    \end{enumerate}

    \begin{enumerate}[resume, label=\roman*),parsep=5pt,
      listparindent=-\dimexpr\leftmargini+\leftmarginii\relax]
        \item{Question 3:}

    \myanswer{My third answer}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way I can get this to break cross pages? Long answers seem to cause the page to overflow.

Comment: @VortixDev As it is currently formulated, no page breaking across an answer, but let me think a bit more.

Comment: @VortixDev Please see my revised answer

Answer (score 2):

You could use the TeX primitive `\parshape` to escape the indentation introduced by all list environments. The following should do what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum} %% <- for \lipsum

\makeatletter   %% <- make @ usable in macro names
\newcommand*\answer[1]{%
  \begingroup   %% <- limit scope of the following changes
    \par        %% <- start a new paragraph
    \@totalleftmargin=0pt \linewidth=\columnwidth
    %% ^^ let other commands know that the margins have been reset
    \parshape 0
    %% ^^ reset the margins
    #1\par      %% <- insert #1 and end this paragraph
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother    %% <- revert @

\begin{document}

\lipsum[66]

\begin{enumerate}
\item
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*)]

    \item
        Question 1:
    \answer{\lipsum[75]}

    \item
        Question 2:
    \answer{\lipsum[75]}

    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You could alternatively define an `answer` environment using

```
\makeatletter %% <- make @ usable in macro names
\newenvironment*{answer}{%
  \par
  \@totalleftmargin=0pt \linewidth=\columnwidth
  \parshape 0
}{\par}
\makeatother %% <- revert @
```

---

### About `\parshape`:

Under the hood, all list commands use `\parshape` to change the margins.
Though it can be used to [do a lot more](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32257/156366), if you just want to change the indentation/width of the current (and all subsequent) paragraphs you can call

```
\@totalleftmargin=<new indentation> \linewidth=<new line width>
\parshape 1 \@totalleftmargin \linewidth
```

You could also just write `\parshape 1 <new indentation> <new width>`, but then other commands (such as the list environments) inside the paragraph won't know what margins you have set (and assume the old values). `\parshape 0` undoes the effect of previously issued `\parshape`s.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The command works perfectly, though when I try to use the environment, I get "You can't use '/spacefactor' in vertical mode", as well as "Missing $ inserted".

Comment: That's because the definition of the environment, like that of `\answer`, should be surrounded by `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` (because `\@totalleftmargin` contains an `@`). I'll add these. See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106175/156366) for more information.